# Can't trigger the close button click event from the Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this burger menu which I can't invoke the button onclick event function when I click it.

HTML code:

```
<button class="nav-aside-close"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
```

JQuery code:

```
$('.nav-aside-close').on('click', function () {  
     console.log('test');  
     $('#nav-aside').removeClass('active');
     $('#nav').removeClass('shadow-active');
});
```

If I click any area outside the burger menu, it works. Below is the code which works:

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
        if (!$(event.target).closest($('#nav-aside')).length) {
            if ($('#nav-aside').hasClass('active')) {
                $('#nav-aside').removeClass('active');
                $('#nav').removeClass('shadow-active');
            } else {
                if ($(event.target).closest('.aside-btn').length) {
                    $('#nav-aside').addClass('active');
                    $('#nav').addClass('shadow-active');
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Actual code I have uploaded it at http://js.findingsteve.net

Comment: Are you see you have the click handler attached to the `X` button? I am not seeing it on the registered events though. And nice app BTW!

Comment: hi, how do I check this? thanks @jom :) but if view from IE , it looks suck lol

Comment: I really meant to say "Are you **sure**..." on my previous comment.  BTW, @Steve who cares with IE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Chrome, open up DevTools (F12) and do this on the Console tab and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
getEventListeners(document.querySelector('button.nav-aside-close'))
```

If you see any `click` events registered, it should work.

Anyway, I noticed you are putting the `main.js` file on the `<head>` and not using [`jQuery.ready`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/), so your click handler is essentially never attached since the DOM element is not ready by the time the script executes.

#### Solution:

Add the jQuery alias `$` on the very first line of your JS file, that is a [shorthand for `jQuery.ready`](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) BTW.

```
$(function($) {
    "use strict"

    // Fixed Nav
    var lastScrollTop = 0;
```

Don't forget to also remove the jQuery function assignment from the end of the line, since it's no longer an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE).

```
    setStickyPos();

})(jQuery);
```

**Alternative**, you can keep everything as is and move your `main.js` file to the `<body>` element, right before the closing `</body>` tag. That is pretty much the same as having the scripts executed when all the elements above it have finished loading.

Comment: omg just adding the $ fixed it even I didn't change the rest of the original code. thanks  a lot.

Comment: No problem. Glad it helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because `.nav-aside-close` is hidden in the initial render.

Try this instead:

```
$("#nav").on("click", ".nav-aside-close", function() {
  $("#nav-aside").removeClass("active");
  $("#nav").removeClass("shadow-active");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Based in @Ana Liza Pandac comment

It should be:

```
$("#nav").on("click", "#nav-aside .nav-aside-close", function() {
  $("#nav-aside").removeClass("active");
  $("#nav").removeClass("shadow-active");
});
```

Your tree is: nav->nav-aside and obj with class nav-aside-close

The difference is on: 
 $("#nav").on("click", "#**nav-aside** .nav-aside-close", function()

Comment: still the same but i fixed it now with @jom solution